# Backup of Workflow in SharePoint 2010/2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow

Is there anyway in which we can take a backup of the SharePoint designer list workflow in SP2010 or SP2013?

Or any workaround to do this? We were looking at replicatin a workflow from dev to test environment. So, are looking for possible ways to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use content types in your list, allowing you to build reusable workflows, which can be saved as a templates and published to another environment where you can use it in lists with the same content type.